# ACL settings works when using ssh but not with scp command

Tags: linux, ssh, access-control-list, scp

I have setup an Arch Linux machine with a user 'archie' with a primary group 'users' as:

```sh
useradd -m -g users archie
```

Whenever `archie` creates a file in his ~/shared directory I want the group `users` to get write permissions so I add:

```sh
setfacl -dm u::rw,g::rw,o::r ~/shared
```

Now when I'm logged in as `archie` via ssh and create a file in ~/shared I can see that it works:

```sh
touch a.txt
ls -l
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 archie users 0 Dec  6 20:05 a.txt
```

However when I use `scp` from my client the 'w' permission is not set to `users` i.e.:

```sh
scp a.txt archie@192.168.0.1:/home/archie/shared
# now group users only got read permissions:
ls -l
-rw-r-r--+ 1 archie users 0 Dec  6 20:07 a.txt
```

I have no clue why I get this behaviour, shouldn't `scp` kind of works the same way as being logged in with ssh?
How can I configure so I get the same behaviour with `scp`?

Comment: Reminds me of https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2678

Answer (score 0):

This might fix your problem if you use `rwx`.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105831/how-do-i-allow-rwx-access-to-a-specific-group-with-acls

Answer (score 0):

I also could not get this to work with ACLs, but for me `bindfs` was the solution - it works no matter if you are logged in via SSH or use `scp` to copy files there.

```bash
sudo bindfs --create-for-group=users --create-with-perms=u+rwX,g+rwX,o+rX /home/archie/shared /home/archie/shared
```

Or in `/etc/fstab` this would look like:

```
/home/archie/shared /home/archie/shared fuse.bindfs create-for-group=users,create-with-perms=u+rwX,g+rwX,o+rX 0 0
```

See also [Forcing user in both directions using bindfs](https://serverfault.com/questions/669407/forcing-user-in-both-directions-using-bindfs)